# How to properly handle errors while consuming messages?

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

I'm consuming messages with spring-integration-kafka, using a `message-driven-channel-adapter`:

```
<int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter  
    id="kafkaListener"
    listener-container="container1"
    channel="outputFromKafka"
    error-channel="errorChannel"/>
```

The container uses a `JsonDeserializer` to deserialize the incoming JSON to an object:

```
<beans:bean id="container1" class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory">
            <beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:map>
                    <beans:entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="localhost:9092" />
                    <beans:entry key="key.deserializer" value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer" />
                    <beans:entry key="group.id" value="mygroup" />
                </beans:map>
            </beans:constructor-arg>
           <beans:property name="valueDeserializer">
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer">
                    <beans:constructor-arg value="com.foo.MyType"/>
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.config.ContainerProperties">
            <beans:constructor-arg name="topics" value="foo" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

If the message can't be parsed successfully (e.g. because the consumer accidentally uses the wrong type), an exception is thrown:

```
ERROR org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Uncaught error in request completion: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data ...
```

After this, the adapter is receiving the same message again (probably because the last one wasn't committed?), and fails in exactly the same way, resulting in an endless stream of exceptions.

It looks like the configured `error-channel` is not used.

What are the options to handle errors like this, and how is it configured in XML?

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like the configured error-channel is not used.

What makes you believe that?

I just ran a test with the error channel set to `errorChannel` (the default, with a logging adapter)...

```
12:06:08.366 [container-kafka-consumer-1] ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - ...
```

Can you provide a debug log snippet for `org.springframework.integration` showing a failure?

**EDIT**

Oh, sorry...

```
ERROR org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Uncaught error in request completion: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data ...
```

That's much lower down in the stack before Spring Integration gets the message.

Comment: See my edit - you would need to customize the deserializer to catch the exception and return something that indicates the failure to deserializer. i.e. some "special" `MyType` instance.

Comment: You're right; the exceptions that are thrown by a `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer` are simply caught and logged by the Kafka client code, without any possibility to intervene.
Using a magic instance of the deserialized type is technically possible, but violates quite a few of my principles ;)

Comment: Maybe using a Kafka value deserializer isn't a good choice for JSON then. Instead, a StringDeserializer and a separate json to object transformer gives more flexibility and robustness, I think.

Comment: Yes, and then the `errorChannel` will get the exception.